# Is it possible to get the source/raw query of a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

input:

```
df = pyspark.createDataFrame([{"col1":1}])

df = df.filter(df['col1']==1)

print(source_query(df))
```

Output:

```
select * from df where col1=1
```

Answer (score 2):

The operations performed over spark dataframe are optimized using catalyst optimizer, So here no query is basically being formed.
The catalyst optimizer read the logical plan creates an optimized logical plan using the rules defined in the catalyst optimizer and then generates physical plan which in the end performs the rdd equivalent operation.

I have never seen a query being generated out of the dataframe operations.